# Salesforce How to remove Log in here link on Site login page

Tags: visualforce

I would like to remove the Log in here link on Site login page as below:

[image]
my solution is create a new login page and override the default one, but I wonder if there is any other way to do it. If you have any idea about this,  it will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change your right side IFRAME content from here :

- From Setup, click Domain Management | My Domain.
- Under Login Page Setting, click Edit.
- To customize your login, upload an image.
- Images can be .jpg, .gif, or .png files up to 100 KB in size. Maximum
  image size is 250px by 125px.
- To customize your login page background, click the Select a color or
  enter a valid hexadecimal color code.
- **Enter the URL of the file to be included in the right-side iframe on
  the login page.**
- **Content must be located at a URL that uses SSL encryption and the
  https:// prefix. Maximum content size is 478px by 397px.**
- Optionally, select authentication services to provide as identity
  providers on the login page.
- Click Save.

you can use this URL as sample just to check how it looks :
**https://www.salesforce.com/in/mobile/features/**